# iFrame form submit and alert after result

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a hidden iFrame with a form like this:

```
<form name="MyForm" id="SaveForm" target="MyFrame">
.....
</form>
<iframe name="MyFrame" height="0" width="0" style="display: none"></iframe>
```

After an action, i get my form and i perform a `submit`

```
MyForm.submit();
```

What i need is a "result" (as alert) when the form has finished the communication with the server.

I've tried to write the `callback` in this way, but i dont know where to put it...

```
function callbackQrContext() {
    window.parent.alert('finished!');
}
```

I cant use jQuery, Ajax and so on.

Comment: can you use xhttp?

Comment: Yes, but not jQuery.. i cant use ajax:bind or something similar... i havent jQuery (and i cant install it) on my application.

Comment: did you take a look at the [`window.postMessage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) ?

Comment: Mhhh no... now i look on it. What i have forgot to say is that i have to use Internet Explorer (no Chrome, no Firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var ajx;
ajx=new XMLHttpRequest();
ajx.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (ajx.readyState == 4 && ajx.status == 200) {
  callbackQrContext(ajx);
}
ajx.open("GET", "yoururl", true);
ajx.send();
```